# Need help getting "ERROR: Exception:" when trying to start weubui-use

Tags: stable-diffusion

Keep getting this error below
[Error: Exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/99koQ.png)Already up to date.
I've already delete the venv folder and install using python 3.10.6 version
I have try delete everything and reinstall stable diffusion, but keep getting the same error.
I have no clue what to do now so any help would really apricated.